# Cannot download file PDF from chrome pdf viewer run on 'https server'

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, https, openssl, tcpdf

Using 'TCPDF' library to generate file pdf, then view with *chrome browser* as well but **when i click download** from this viewer I get **Feiled - Network Error** at bottom of my browser. This problem happen when my server run on **SSL**. So how could I solve this? plz help.

> Image:
>   [image]

Comment: note: this application need to run with SSL (https).

Comment: I can download a PDF with that button from a self-signed server, so it's something else. Try chrome://net-export/

Comment: Are you creating the PDF from POST request?

Comment: Yes, this one i render in POST.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=...`, try changing `inline` to `attachment`.

The PDF wouldn't display in browser anymore, but it will download correctly.